# IE8 submit upload form with jquery and with click trigger

Tags: forms, internet-explorer-8, upload, triggers

Can someone tell me why this piece of code does not work in IE8, but in IE8+ and all others work ok?

```
<form action="upload.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form">
    <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload-file">
</form>              
<button id="chooseFile">Choose file</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){

        $('#chooseFile').on('click', function(e){
            //$('#upload-form').submit(); //this fire when choose file
            $('#upload-file').trigger('click'); //this fire event below successfully
            return false;
        });

        $('#upload-file').on('change', function () {
            alert(1); //alert is firing in IE8 so event fire
            $(this).parent().submit(); //this not work in IE8
            $('#upload-form').submit(); //this also not work in IE8 
            return false;

        });
    });
</script>
```

All i want is submit form after click on #chooseFile btn, in change event.

Please help

Comment: I'm having a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046928/file-upload-ie8-inputtype-file-filled-in-by-triggering-with-javascript-empt), did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I have not found a solution...